# Why is sorting an array in PHP so slow?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting, nlp

I'm implementing a class that tries to detect stop words on a corpus. One of the methods in said class is, of course, `idf()`:

```
public function idf(){

    // 1) In how many articles does each term appear
    $tokensFreq = $this->computeTokensFreq();

    // 2) Applies the IDF formula (array format : $term => $idf)
    $tokensIDF = $this->computeIDF($tokensFreq);

    // 3) Sort array so that 'stopwords' (smaller idfs) appear at the top
    arsort($tokensIDF);

    return $tokensIDF;

}
```

The problem is, this function is veeery slow: it takes more than 5 minutes to go through a relatively small array of 4 006 tokens.

At first, I thought I misimplemented the algorithm (I even replaced all `array_key_exists` with `isset`). But after further inspection, it turned out that it's the `arsort` call who takes the lion part of the execution time.

To help reduce the load, I added the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag to the `arsort` function, but in vain.

First of all, is it normal that sorting such an array takes up all that time?
Secondly, and most importantly, what can I do to make things go smoother?

Comment: Just as a minor point.... `arsort()` is "by reference", so `$sortedIDF` is simply a Boolean true/false indicating if the sort was successful.... is that really what the code is supposed to return?

Comment: And the answer is "no" a sort should never take that long for a 4000 element array

Comment: @MarkBaker: definitly not (^^') code refactored ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker: that's what I thought too. But if I comment out the `arsort` line, the function prints out in a much shorter time after running through the same corpus.

Comment: Well arsort certainly shouldn't take that length of time, but the timing of the overall script may not be directly affected by that one line taking a long time to execute.... it may be that other parts of the script are affected (and run more quickly) because they're reading data from that array in an unsorted state.... it may be that a slow loop elsewhere in the code will run through all 4000 elements if they're correctly sorted; but only loop over the first few if they're not sorted

Comment: Rather than judging the speed of a single function call based on the time to execute the entire script, you should use a profiler (such as xdebug) to identify actual call times for individual functions - http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: Actually, I stumbled upon this issue while testing this freshly implemented function, and for the time being, no further processing is being conducted on its output, it's just being `print_r`d out. 
Though, I really loved the link you sent on your last comment. Very interesting indeed. I'll see what how it can help me. Thanks!